# Does stackoverflow give a notification if chat permission request was denied?

Tags: support, chat

I requested access to a members only chat room. It showed "waiting for access" so I decided to browse around other rooms and request access to another one. Checking back today, I saw that the second room allows me to chat, but the first one now says "Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the faq for more information." It's as if I never asked for permission.

Does this mean that I was denied? I have nothing in my inbox/notifications.

Comment: If you go to info>access, you can see if your request is pending/accepted/declined(in which case you can't see it anywhere)

Comment: Yeah, shame that there isn't a clear cut notification and shame that SE allows users to lock their rooms. It seems to go against the whole "community" mentality.

Comment: have your room spammed by people and you may see the difference. There's no shortage of rooms, generally there's an unlocked  room for every locked one. And the unlocked room is full of crap (not spam, but people trying to advertise their posts, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I went ahead and requested access to that room again.

If you get denied, you **don't** get a notification.